# Android: How to know which launcher icon/activity started the application, given application context?

Tags: android, android-application-class, taskaffinity

I have created a lib that when you add to your app adds a 2nd launcher icon (it'll be used for debugging network), the lib could be initialized from the application using its context or from an activity, I'd like to know in my lib if the application was launched from the 2nd launcher icon or another one.

One more thing I have different `taskAfinity` for my 2nd launcher.

The lib is also open source here: https://github.com/shehabic/sherlock

Comment: An Activity is started from one of the two sources?

Comment: no, Application could be started from 2 different Launcher Activities, I'd like at the application level if the user initialized my lib in the Application's onCreate which launcher icon was used to start the activity

Comment: I don't think you can do this. With an Activity or Service, you could add an extra to the launch Intent and then read that in the Activity to know the source. But the Application class doesn't have that.